# Representation of tuple applicative

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand the tuple applicative. When I look at information in prelude about tuple, it says:

```
instance (Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (a, b)
instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a)
```

What does `((,) a)` mean? It does not look like a tuple.

I have following example:

```
Prelude Data.Monoid> ((Sum 2), (+2)) <*> ((Sum 45), 8)
(Sum {getSum = 47},10)
```

The first argument in the tuple is an instance of monoid and the second it is just a function application. But how does the signature `((,) a)` match the example above?

Comment: `(a,b)` is the type constructor `(,)` applied to `a` and `b`. It can also be written `(,) a b`. `(,) a` is the type constructor `(,)` partially applied to `a`. The applicative instance for `(,) a` takes the monoidal sum of the 1st component in `<*>`; for the 2nd component, the same logic is used as that for `Identity` (but you can see this by looking at the source code for that instance).

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to write the instance as a tuple section (which is not actually legal Haskell, but gets the point across:

```
instance Monoid a => Applicative (a,)
```

... and before discussing that, consider

```
instance Functor (a,)
```

What this does is just: for any left-hand element (of type `a`), map over whichever right-hand argument there is. I.e.

```
  fmap :: (b -> c) -> (a,b) -> (a,c)
```

One might at this point wonder why we have `(a,)` and not `(,a)`. Well, mathematically speaking, the following is just as valid:

```
instance Functor (,a)
  fmap :: (a -> b) -> (a,c) -> (b,c)
```

...however that can't be defined because `(a,b)` is in fact syntactic sugar for `(,) a b`, i.e. the tuple-type-constructor `(,)` applied first to the `a` type and then to the `b` type. Now, in `instance Functor (a,)`, we simply leave the `b` open to be fmapped over, hence

```
instance Functor ((,) a)
```

But it's not possible to _only apply the `b` argument, while leaving `a` open – that would require a sort of type-level lambda

```
“instance Functor (\b -> (a,b))”
```

which is not supported.

Now as to `Applicative` – that just extends the `(a,)` functor to also support combinations of multiple tuples, provided there's already a *natural way* to combine the `a` elements – that's what the `Monoid` instance offers. This is better known as the [Writer monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#g:1), because it's well suited for generating a “operations log” along with the actual computation results:

```
Prelude> ("4+", (4+)) <*> ("10",10)
("4+10",14)
```

Comment: Isn't there a language pragma to allow tuple sections? Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: `{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}` only works at the value level AFAIK.

Comment: Ah, OK. That's what I'm thinking of.